# Crystal reports parameters using a command to an Oracle database

Tags: oracle11g, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to create a report that has three optional parameters using a command in Crystal Reports 2008. The only one I can't get to work is the date parameter (seems Oracle does not treat dates the same as SQL Server).

I want the user to be able to pick and choose which parameter they would like to use; one, two, or all three. It works beautifully when I run it in TOAD and hard code the dates, but it will not run in Crystal reports using the syntax to create the parameters.

I have done this a thousand times in a SQL server environment but can't get it to work in Oracle.

The field is type is `DATE` in the Oracle table.

Here is the syntax from my Report command for the 3 parameters:

```
AND ( ( CLIL. ITEM_TAG IN ('{?tag}') OR CLS.DESCRIPTION IN( '{?desc}')
OR trunc (CLIL.ISSUE_DATE) BETWEEN to_date ('{?StartDate}', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date ('{?EndDate}', 'mm/dd/yyyy' )))
```

Answer (score 0):

Crystal reports doesn't accept the `Oracle` syntax.. you need to use the functions provided by the CR to do manuplations of dates... and then use that in CR.

Create a `Start Date` and `End Date` as date parameters in CR and then use those.

```
(CLIL.ISSUE_DATE) >= {?StartDate} and (CLIL.ISSUE_DATE) < {?EndDate}
```

Here start date and end date are `Date` datatype parameters.

if `(CLIL.ISSUE_DATE)` is a datetime parameter then use the function `Cdate` provided by the crystal.